# not able to open file with fopen function in c using Turbo C

Tags: turbo-c

I am using Turbo C. for below program when I debug code  I always get the "Cannot read file" on output window.  Input path of file is given as "PR1.txt" and same file present on C: as well.

```
  #include "stdio.h"
  #include "stdlib.h"

  void main(void)
  {
   FILE *fp;
   int value;
   char ch;
   fp = fopen("PR1.txt","w");
   if(!fp)
   {
       printf("Cannot read file");
   }
   else
   {
      printf ("\n entr char to wrtite in file ::");
      scanf("%c",&value);
      fputc(ch,fp);
      fclose(fp);
      fp=fopen("PR1.c","r") ;
      value=getc(fp);
      printf("\n The result is= %d",value);
      fclose(fp);
      getch();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, your program will try to find the file in the location where you are executing the program. So make sure your data file is in the same folder or put the full path with the filename.